# Using a Custom Django FilterSet and OrderingFilter at the Same Time Breaks My FilterSet

Tags: python, django

So I have MyFilterSet and CustomOrderingFilter both working perfectly by themselves but when I try to put both into the view at the same time the FilterSet breaks. I've removed the unnecessary business logic from the functions and just included the parts that matter.

I tried to put the OrderingFilter inside the FilterSet (to no avail).

(There are no errors generated. I'm using Django 1.11.4, Python 2.7.17 and PostgreSQL 10.23 and it will be near impossible to change those versions at the moment but if changing is the answer I'd like to know that too.)

in filters.py:

```
    class MyFilterSet(FilterSet):
    
        id = filters.NumberFilter(name='id', lookup_expr='exact')
    
        class Meta:
            model = TheModel
            fields = list()
            exclude = []
    
    class CustomOrderingFilter(OrderingFilter):
        fields_related = {
            'vendor': {         'data_type': 'text',
                                'loc': 'thing__vendor',},
        }
    
        def get_ordering(self, request, queryset, view):
            param = request.query_params.get(self.ordering_param)
            if param:
                return param
            return self.get_default_ordering(view)
    
        def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
            ordering = self.get_ordering(request, queryset, view)
            if ordering in self.fields_related.keys():
                return queryset.order_by(ordering)
            return queryset
```

in views.py

```
    class getMyListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
        serializer_class = MySerializer
        filter_class = MyFilterSet
        filter_backends = [CustomOrderingFilter]
    
        def get_queryset(self):
            models = TheModel.objects
            return models
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing your default filter backends in settings looks like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend']
}
```

and when you just use filter_class

```
filter_class = MyFilterSet
```

it works because it's using the DjangoFilterBackend already. But when you wanted to add CustomOrderingFilter, you overrode this setting and neglected to add DjangoFilterBackend again. So DjangoFilterBackend isn't there anymore.

I am guessing this should work for you:

```py
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class getMyListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    filter_class = MyFilterSet
    filter_backends = [CustomOrderingFilter, DjangoFilterBackend]

    def get_queryset(self):
        models = TheModel.objects
        return models
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This was the solution <3